What is a "Ｐ学生"?
A story I'm reading has a character referring to a girl as a "Ｐ学生", and I've been completely unable to find a definition for what it is. The girl is an elementary school student so it can't be "preschool," and "producer" wouldn't make sense, given how I've seen P used in other places. I have an inkling that it's used in an inappropriate context however, given that this character is very much not a good person.

Makes no sense to me either. Could you give some context (hopefully, a paragraph long)?

For context, this line is from a ""comedy"" side story for a visual novel. The original VN features a teacher who abuses a student and then murders her, who later comes back as a youkai. In the side story, the teacher uses literal descriptions of her as a "眼鏡Ｐ学生の妖怪", or "glasses-wearing P-student youkai", and the P part is what's throwing me off.

Is it possible that "P" stands for "poltergeist" or "phantom".... something to indicate that this student is a ghost?

Doesn't make sense for it to be poltergeist since the last line of the story is the teacher wanting to go back in time and tell himself to leave the "glasses P student" alone, indicating before she becomes a youkai

It must be for this.

Ah, so it's a censor bleep. That makes a lot of sense.
